# Sitecore - SSL selected pages

Tags: sitecore

In my sitecore website, I need few pages to be SSL enabled. (User profile, Login, Create data etc). But I want to leave browsing related pages normally.

Is there a Sitecore configuation to do this, or how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Sitecore 6.0+, check out the [SSL Redirector module](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/SSL_Redirector.aspx) in the Sitecore marketplace.

This module will allow you to specify the specific pages (templates really) that you want to be secure.  I think this is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that we took was:

1. You could create a custom template called Page Security and have a field called Https of type check box.
2. Inherit your pages, on which you need Https, from that template and have the check box ticked.
3. Lastly write a custom code to modify the HttpRequest Pipeline.

   ```
   using Sitecore;
   using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
   using Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest;

   public class HttpsRequestBegin
   {
        public void Process()
        {
             Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = Context.Item;
             if (item != null && item.Fields["Https"] != null)
             {
                  Sitecore.Data.Fields.CheckboxField httpsEnabledCheckbox = new CheckboxField(item.Fields["Https"]);
                  if (httpsEnabledCheckbox.Checked)
                  {
                      // Do Stuff
                  }
              }
        }
   }
   ```

Hope the above helps.

Comment: if (httpsEnabledCheckbox.Checked) then Redirect to HTTPS page. Else do nothing.